# Do first 10 iterations of for each loop - java

Tags: java, foreach, jsoup

I currently have the below code. I am looking to only do the first 10 iterations of the for each loop that adds the "DogDetail" to the TableView instead of the amount of records that might be extracted from the webpage.

For example: If a "Dog" has 50 history records, I would only like to "get" 10 of them, to slow down the time taken to run the program.

```
public void loadHistory() throws IOException{
    //races = new ArrayList<Race>();

    Dog dog = (Dog)tblRunners.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String selectedDog = dog.getName();
    lblRunner.setText(selectedDog);

    //getHistory
    String dogPage = "http://www.gbgb.org.uk/raceCard.aspx?dogName=" + selectedDog;
    Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(dogPage).get();

    Element tblHeader = doc1.select("table.MasterTable_Web20 tbody").first();
    List<DogDetail> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Element element1 : tblHeader.children()){
        DogDetail dogDetail = new DogDetail();
        dogDetail.setDate(element1.select("td:eq(0)").text());
        // System.out.println((element1.select("td:eq(0)").text()));
        dogDetail.setDistance(element1.select("td:eq(2)").text());
        dogDetail.setFin(element1.select("td:eq(4)").text());
        dogDetail.setTrack(element1.select("td:eq(7)").text());
        String raceURLlong1 = (element1.select("td:eq(14)").html());
        String raceURLlong2 = raceURLlong1.replace("<a href=\"","");
        String raceURL = "http://www.gbgb.org.uk/" + raceURLlong2.replace("\">View Race</a>","");
        data.add(dogDetail);

        Document document = Jsoup.connect(raceURL).get(); 
        XElements element = Xsoup.compile("//*[@id=\"content\"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[4]").evaluate(document);

        // Get text content
        String textContent = element.getElements().get(0).childNode(0).toString();

        // Extract time portion
        String time = textContent.trim().replaceAll("\\&nbsp\\;",
                " ").split("\\s+")[1];
        dogDetail.setTime(time);
    }

    // TableView<DogDetail> tblHistory = new TableView<DogDetail>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data));
    // tblHistory.setItems();
    ObservableList<DogDetail> tmp2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(data);
    tblHistory.setItems(tmp2);
}
```

Comment: In what way is your program not already able to accomplish this?

Comment: use an integer counter and break when it reaches 10.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure where to put the counter though? At the moment I seem to just print out the same record 10 times, rather than the first 10 records...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just above your for each loop, do as Kakarot says and initialize an integer counter:

```
int forCounter = 0;
```

Inside your for each loop, increment this counter (probably as the last line of the loop, although technically it is irrelevant where you do this).

```
forCounter++;
```

Then, as the first line of your for each loop, check whether your counter has reached the maximum iterations you want, and break if so.

```
if (forCounter >= maxIterations) break;
```

Just FYI, this is sort of an exercise of why using a for loop might be better than using a for each loop as you have done.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. Think I need to do some more research into loops and breaks! Thanks Again.

Comment: `List#subList` is a method specifically provided *not* to require reaching for the plain for-loop or hacks like a counter and `break`.

Answer (score 4):

You have posted a lot of code not related to your actual question, but it's still missing the essential piece: the return type of `tblHeader.children()`. I shall assume that it is `List`. In that case, you should replace the following:

```
for (Element element1 : tblHeader.children()) {
```

with

```
List<Element> children = tblHeader.children();
for (Element element1 : children.subList(0, Math.min(10, children.size())) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a control variable either as part of the for loop or as a variable outside of the for loop:

```
// Make sure to account for cases where there are less than 10 children
for ( int i = 0; i < 10 || i == tblHeader.getChildren().size(); i++ ) {
    Element element = tblHeader.getChildren().get(i);
    [...]
}
```

or

```
int i = 0;
for ( Element element1 : tblHeader.getChildren() ) {
    if ( i >= 10 || i == tblHeader.getChildren().size()) break;
    [...]
    i++;
}
```